# Ask Question mothership is flying too low! Causes random question asking

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking, mothership

Since the rollout of the almighty new Stack Exchange whatsit bar, the Ask Question Mothership has been flying low:

[image]

This has the effect that clicking on certain links (ie: delete/flags/close in the mod tools) can lead you to the ask a question page, due to the overlap.

Running Chrome 31.0.1650.57m/Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16721

Comment: Reproducible Firefox 25.0.1 Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Same in IE 11.0.9600.16438 (probably same across the board, really)

Comment: clearly The Mothership(tm) doesn't like delete. (I'll push a fix for this)

Comment: `#nav-askquestion {margin-top: -15px}` in a css file solves the thingy *for now*

Comment: @Jin did you only fix it on the main site?  It still seems to be off on meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this. I believe main site's change is already live. The meta will fix will live after the next prod build.